# How to turn off Auto Refresh on "Stock Price" Data Type in Excel

Tags: excel

Since yesterday, my excel files are automatically updating the Stock Prices.

And for my use, that is really bad.

It updates randomly after a while that im using the excel file, or when I open it

What can it be?

It is happenning in all the files and it didnt happen before, is there any configuration that im not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but how are we supposed to know how to help you when you’ve provided zero information about how the workbook gets said stock prices? You need to provide some insight as to how your workbook is built.

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation! There is a new configuration to excel, that for default, updates your data types at every 5 minutes:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-refresh-linked-data-types-44cd357f-4679-4c2e-bc65-1e3dcf94809f